# Meteor collection in ui-router resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, angular-ui-router, resolve

I'm trying to use meteor angular js ui-router resolve to load information of one user selected from user list.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('userprofile', {
        url: '/user/:userId',
        cache: false,
        template: '<user-profile userinfo="$resolve.userinfo"></user-profile>',
        controller: UserProfile,
        controllerAs: name,
        resolve: {
            userinfo: function($stateParams) {
                viewedUser = Meteor.users.findOne({
                    _id: $stateParams.userId
                });

                return viewedUser;
            },
        }
    });
```

The problem is that, for the first time after from user list, user profile display correctly. However, page reload makes the userinfo becomes undefined.
I guest that from second time, the controller loaded already so that it display before resolve done?!

After a while searching, I tried $q and $timeout

```
        resolve: {
            userinfo: function($stateParams, $q, $timeout) {
                deferred = $q.defer();

                $timeout(function() {
                    deferred.resolve(Meteor.users.findOne({
                        _id: $stateParams.userId
                    }));
                }, 1000);

                return deferred.promise;
            },
        }
```

It works as I expected, user profile displayed every time I refresh the page.
But if I lower the delay to 500, it back to undefined when refreshed.
I not sure why in this case, longer delay works?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that I use,

resolve: {
    currentUser: ($q) => {
      var deferred = $q.defer();

```
  Meteor.autorun(function () {
    if (!Meteor.loggingIn()) {
      if (Meteor.user() == null) {
        deferred.reject('AUTH_REQUIRED');
      } else {
        deferred.resolve(Meteor.user());
      }
    }
  });

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

}

This is from a tutorial by @urigo somewhere, which took me some time to find, but it works like a charm.

This code is handy to trap the case where authentication is required - put it at the top level in a .run method

```
function run($rootScope, $state) {
  'ngInject';

  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError',
    (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) => {
      console.log("$stateChangeError: "+error);
      if (error === 'AUTH_REQUIRED') {
        $state.go('login');
      }
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this routes in resolve

if you use angular-meteor

```
resolve: { 
     'loginRequired': function ($meteor, $state) {
                        return $meteor.requireUser().then(function (user) {
                                if (user._id) {return true;}
                            }).catch(function () {
                                $state.go('login');
                                return false;
                            });
                     }
    }
```